# Suppose that x is a real number, $x \neq 0$, and x + 1/x is an integer. Prove that for all $n \geq 1, x^n + 1/x^n$ is an integer.

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I'm reading the book *How to prove it*. I'm not sure about the correctness of my proof to this [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyw36.png).

We have to prove $ \forall n \in N(n\geq 1 \to x^n+1/x^n \text{ is an integer}) $ . We proceed by strong induction. Let $ n \in N $ be arbitrary and suppose $ \forall k<n(k\geq 1 \to x^k+1/x^k \text{ is an integer}) $. Suppose $ n\geq 1 $. Then we have the following cases:

Case 1: $ n=1 $. We already now that $ x+1/x $ is an integer.
Case 2: $ n>1 $. If we let $ k=n-1<n $, then by inductive hypothesis $ x^{n-1}+1/x^{n-1} $ is an integer. It follows that $ (x+1/x)(x^{n-1}+1/x^{n-1}) $ is also an integer. Expanding the product we get $ (x^{n}+{{1}\over{x^{n}}})+(x^{n-2}+x^{2-n}) $. Therefore $ x^{n}+{{1}\over{x^{n}}} $ is an integer, as required.

How can i be sure that $ x^{n}+{{1}\over{x^{n}}} $ is indeed an integer and not a real number?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You are almost there. (a) Use strong induction, in this case use that $x^{n-2} + 1/x^{n-2}$ is an integer. (b) Subtract. *What are the possible values for $x$ in this case anyway? Maybe there is a different proof.*

Comment: There is a small technical gap in the proof. When $n = 2,$ the sum $x^{n-2} + 1/x^{n-2}$ is not covered by the inductive hypothesis. It is still true, but it is true for a different reason.

Comment: So should I let $k=n-2$? From there how do I prove that $x^n+1/x^n$ is an integer? I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: @DavidK To cover that case, should I add to the proof that when $n=2$ the hypothesis is vacuously true?

Comment: No, the hypothesis is not vacuously true when $n=2.$ You have extra work (not much!) to do in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hole in the inductive step as given in the question,
because strong induction on a statement $P(n)$ with a base case $n=1$ only gives you $P(k)$ for $1 \leq k \leq n - 1$ during the inductive step.
And if all you know in the inductive step is that $n > 1,$ you don't know that
$n - 2 \geq 1,$ therefore you cannot assume $P(n - 2)$ during the inductive step.

As it turns out, $P(0)$ is true for other reasons: $x^0 + 1/x^0$ is an integer
(why?), which covers $P(n-2)$ when $n = 2,$ and when $n > 2$ then $n-2 \geq 1$
and $P(n-2)$ **is** covered by the strong induction assumption.
So if you're careful, you can still complete the inductive step, but it requires two cases: one case for $n=2$ and another case for $n > 2.$

But you don't need strong induction. It is sufficient to use ordinary induction to prove a stronger statement: given that $x + 1/x$ is an integer,

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N. (n \geq 1 \implies 
(\text{$x^n+1/x^n$ is an integer}) \land
(\text{$x^{n+1}+1/x^{n+1}$ is an integer}). $$

Notice how your inductive proof uses only the "last two values of $n$",
that is, from $k = n-1$ you get that $x^{n-1}+1/x^{n-1}$ is an integer
and from $k = n-2$ you get that $x^{n-2}+1/x^{n-2}$ is an integer.
You don't need to refer to any other values of $k$.

The stronger statement gives you two consecutive integers $x^k + 1/x^k$
and $x^{k+1} + 1/x^{k+1}$ during the inductive step, even for simple (not strong) induction, which is what you need.
It also means you don't need to cover any special cases during the inductive step.
The trade-off is that you must prove that $x^2 + 1/x^2$ is an integer for the base case.
But if you look at what happens in your proof in the case $n=2,$ this part of the base case is easily dealt with.

Comment: Thank your for the clear explanation. Here is my revised [proof](https://i.imgur.com/F58Ogom.png). Note that I used strong induction since that's what the author probably wanted.

Comment: @G.Ajello It looks fine to me. I agree it is a good idea to use the proof method that is expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you assume in the induction case is $x^n+(1/x^n)$ is an integer for all $0\le n\le k, k\ge1$. Then from your product

$[x^k+(1/x^k)][x+(1/x)]=x^{k+1}+x^{k-1}+(1/x^{k-1})+(1/x^{k+1})=[x^{k-1}+(1/x^{k-1})]+[x^{k+1}+(1/x^{k+1})]$

you infer that

$[x^k+(1/x^k)][x+(1/x)]-[x^{k'1}+(1/x^{k-1})]=[x^{k+1}+(1/x^{k+1})]$

where the left side is a difference of integers so the right side is an integer too, thus you enable $k$ to be incremented by $1$.

Comment: I think I get it now, correct me if I'm still wrong: If we let $ k=n-1<n $, then by inductive hypothesis $ x^k+1/x^k $ is an integer. It follows that $ (x+1/x)(x^k+1/x^k) $ is also an integer. Expanding the product we get $ (x^{k-1}+1/x^{k-1})+(x^{k+1}+1/x^{k+1}) $. Since $ (x+1/x)(x^k+1/x^k)-(x^{k-1}+1/x^{k-1}) $ is an integer, $ x^{k+1}+1/x^{k+1} $ is also an integer. Substituting $ k $ for $ n-1 $ we get $ x^n-1/x^n $, as required.

Comment: I think you need to swap $k-1$ and $k+1$ terms in at least one place. Or is that left as an exercise for the reader? Also look out for the case $n=2.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=x^n+x^{-n}$. Your computation shows that $$a_1a_n=a_{n+1}+a{n-1}$$
As we are given that $a_1$ is an integer, we learn that

> If $a_n$ and $ a_{n-1}$ are integers, then so is $a_{n+1}$.

Now if we let $P(n)=$“both $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ are integers”, we just found $$P(n)\implies P(n+1)$$
So for a nice induction, we need $P(1)$. One part is given, and $a_0=2$.